# How to remove error limit in Clang Libtooling?

Tags: clang, clang++, libtooling

I made C/C++ source code modification tool using Clang Libtooling. I ran into the following error while executing my tool on test programs.

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

But I would like for the tool to ignore this limit, print all the errors, and execute AST modification as normal. Is there a way to fix this problem using Clang Libtooling?

Comment: You need to pass clang the option `-ferror-limit=0`. Possibly by invoking `CommonOptionsParser` with suitable arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dratenik, I solved the problem by adding an ArgumentAdjuster which passes Clang the option  `-ferror-limit=0`.

```
clang::tooling::ClangTool tool(compileDb, filename);
tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(clang::tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(
    "-ferror-limit=0"));
tool.run(...);
```